# how to aws bandwidth report for a year?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bandwidth

I need to calculate AWS Bandwidth usage for an year , from the account activity i cannot see Data transfer option to get the statistics , How can it get it done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on your account name in the top right of the [AWS console](https://console.aws.amazon.com). Choose *Billing & Cost Management*, *Reports*, *AWS Usage Reports* and you can download metrics for almost anything.

You probably want to choose:

- *Service: Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud*
- *Usage Type: DataTransfer-Out-Bytes*

You can then download detailed stats in XML or CSV for any specified time period.

Comment: I don't see `Usage Reports`, I see only `My Account`, `Billing & Cost`, `Management`, `Security Credentials`, `Sign Out`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Billing & Cost Management`:
[image: aws Billing & Cost Management]