# How to trace bandwidth consumption in Amazon Cloud server?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are using Amazon cloud server for our three gaming application. We are facing high Data transfer (bandwidth) in our cloud server; every month it takes more than 9,000 GB data consuming.

I need help to find out data consuming whether someone using our server or some files are frequently access. We are very confident for game application not consuming this much bandwidth.

Comment: So how much bandwidth (for example Mbit/sec) do you expect your application is consuming?

Comment: Hi i don't know how to check. Can you please give me some information then i will check and tell you

Comment: [How do you know your server has been compromised?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7443/how-do-you-know-your-server-has-been-compromised)

Comment: Please see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218839/how-to-aws-bandwidth-report-for-a-year)

Comment: You need to learn how to do basic troubleshooting- looking at logs, analyzing traffic, etc. This is not an AWS issue.